# Почему не рендерится компонент Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Собственно вопрос в заголовке, пишу код как в [руководстве](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html#%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B).
[Вот ссылка на CodePen](https://codepen.io/antonowano/pen/xLPZzp)

```js
Vue.component('todo-item', {
  template: '<li>Hello, World</li>'
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <todo-item></todo-item>
</ul>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно создавать экземпляр Vue:

[https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Использование-компонентов](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

https://codepen.io/antonowano/pen/xLPZzp

```
   Vue.component('todoItem', {
     template: '<li>Hello, World</li>'
   });

   new Vue({
     el: 'ul'
  })
```